# What is the correct way to type hint a homogenous Queue in Python3.6 (especially for PyCharm)?

Tags: pycharm, python-3.6, type-hinting, mypy

I'm writing a fractal generator in Python 3.6, and I use `multiprocessing.Queue`s to pass messages from the main thread to the workers. This is what I've tried so far, but PyCharm doesn't seem to be able to infer attribute types for items taken from the queues:

```
from typing import NamedTuple, Any, Generic, TypeVar, Tuple
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

T = TypeVar()


class Message(NamedTuple):
    method: str
    id: str
    data: Any = None


class TypedQueue(Generic[T]):
    def get(self) -> T:
        ...
    def put(self, m: T) -> None:
        ...


MessageQ = TypedQueue[Message]


class FractalWorker(Process):
    def __init__(self, work: MessageQ, results: MessageQ)
        super().__init__()
        self.work = work
        self.results = results

    @staticmethod
    def make_queues() -> Tuple[MessageQ, MessageQ]:
        work = cast(MessageQ, Queue())
        results = cast(MessageQ, Queue())
        return work, results
```

I want PyCharm to be able to tell that the attributes of the result of `self.work.get` have the types specified by the `Message` class. I also want to know if there is a standard way of type hinting Queues similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TypeVar` should have a name.

`T = TypeVar("T")` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 37):

Old Question, but I just found

```py
P: "Queue[Path]" = Queue()
```

to work with both `queue.Queue` and `multiprocessing.Queue` in PyCharm

Comment: Is `Path` supposed to be a `TypeVar` here @Xtrem532?  Or something else?

Comment: iirc this was a Queue named `P` holding `pathlib.Path` objects

Comment: Nice. I still had to `import multiprocessing` for mypy to pass, even thought IDE didn't tell me.

Answer (score 2):

@Xtrem532's answer worked for me, but if you prefer not to write the type as a string, import `annotations`:

```
from __future__ import annotations

import multiprocessing as mp
import multiprocessing.queues as mpq

q1: mp.Queue[str] = mp.Queue()
q2: mpq.Queue[str] = mpq.Queue(ctx=mp.get_context())
```

I had to use `multiprocessing.queues.Queue` to get pylint to pass.

Comment: I still had to quote it, mypy showed errors about type (meaning Queue) not being subscriptable.