# How to add variable type annotation for what goes into a Queue?

Tags: python, types

e.g.

```
from queue import Queue

q: Queue = Queue()
q.put("abc")
```

This is okay. Now I want to specify the types that go into the queue.

```
from queue import Queue

q: Queue[str] = Queue()
q.put("abc")
```

This gets "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't currently supported by the typing functionality. See this discussion of Python core developers: https://bugs.python.org/issue33315

It also suggests a current workaround, to put the annotation in quotes:

```py
q: "Queue[str]" = Queue()
```

The workaround is that an annotation can be any type (no pun intended). A string is a perfectly acceptable type, but if you want to use non-string annotations, then they have to "behave" properly. You can annotate that something is a `Queue` because, again, an annotation can have any type. But the `Queue` class itself isn't subscriptable, so `Queue[int]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 23):

It is now (as of Python 3.9) possible to subscript `Queue`:

```py
a: Queue[int] = Queue()  # valid
```

Comment: If you want it for Python 3.8: `from __future__ import annotations`

Answer (score 3):

[What is the correct way to type hint a homogenous Queue in Python3.6 (especially for PyCharm)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48956422/what-is-the-correct-way-to-type-hint-a-homogenous-queue-in-python3-6-especially)

```
q: "Queue[str]" = Queue()
```

This would do the trick. Does anyone have any reference to how adding quotes to this make it work?

Comment: In python an annotation (the stuff behind the ':' ) can be anything! In your example you annotate the variable q with a string "Queue[str]", you could also annotate it with "Hello".
However, annotations are regularly used to denote the type of the annotated object. Pycharm, mypy, etc, also process string annotations, and eventually check if they can be interpreted as a type. That was often necessary, if you want to use a type in annotation that was defined laterin the file. That restriction was lifted in python 3.10 i think. now annotations can forward reference declarations in the same file